# Rails Paperclip gem wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm working on my first RoR project and attempting to use the Paperclip gem, but I'm running into an error I can't seem to figure out:

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `create'
>   Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"OBYHA0M+TA93sNF3uqrJ/zvnnEyWJUREn4NcOl0ExfA=",
 "event"=>{"title"=>"",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f803802b1f0 @original_filename="icon.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[image]\"; filename=\"icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130217-21480-1molvwa>>,
 "description"=>"",
 "date"=>"",
 "time"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Event"}
```

I understand that in events_controller.rb in the create method, too many arguments are being passed in. However, I followed the QuickStart instructions on Paperclip's Github so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Here is my code for events_controller.rb

```
def create
    @event = Event.create( params[:event] )
 end
```

Just for debugging, I tried changing the line to Event.create( params[] ), at which point the error changed from wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) to wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).

Here is my code for event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :date, :description, :time, :title, :image
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

I've checked that I'm running the correct versions for everything. I have Paperclip 3.4.0, Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 1.9.3, and ImageMagick 6.8.3-1. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I've looked at quite a few similar problems but most seemed to occur a few years ago and were resolved in subsequent updates to Paperclip. None of the solutions I've found in similar posts have worked for me, and unfortunately I just have enough Rails experience yet to know what's going on. I realize I'm probably making a total newbie mistake, in which case I apologize but would still really appreciate some help to get me on the right track.

Please let me know if any additional code or information would be useful for debugging.

Thanks for your time!

Application trace:

> cocaine (0.3.2) lib/cocaine/command_line.rb:63:in `run'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/helpers.rb:31:in`
>   run'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:18:in
>   `block in geometry_string' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:43:in`silence_stream'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:17:in
>   `geometry_string'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:9:in`
>   make'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:26:in
>   `from_file'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb:35:in`
>   initialize'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in
>   `new'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in`
>   make'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:431:in
>   `block in post_process_style'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:430:in`
>   each'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:430:in
>   `inject'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:430:in`
>   post_process_style'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:423:in
>   `block in post_process_styles'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:422:in`
>   each'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:422:in
>   `post_process_styles'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:415:in`
>   block (2 levels) in post_process' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in
>   `_run__3384881169595487878__image_post_process__96086910066492375__callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   `_run_image_post_process_callbacks' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:26:in
>   `run_paperclip_callbacks'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:414:in`
>   block in post_process' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in
>   `_run__3384881169595487878__post_process__96086910066492375__callbacks' activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_post_process_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:26:in
>   `run_paperclip_callbacks'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:413:in`
>   post_process'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:108:in
>   `assign'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bundler/gems/paperclip-dcd2774e7913/lib/paperclip.rb:200:in`block in has_attached_file' activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in
>   assign_attributes' activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in`each' activerecord
>   (3.2.12) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in
>   `assign_attributes' activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in`initialize' activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new' activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in`create'
>   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `create' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in`
>   *run*_3332570171411252513__process_action_*3320642634939127128*_callbacks' activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in
>   process_action' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
>   activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in`process' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`
>   dispatch' actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in
>   `block in action' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in`
>   call' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
>   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each' journey (1.0.4)
>   lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call' rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in`
>   call' rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
>   activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in`call'
>   activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `_run__1281245379307539657__call__96086910066492375__callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
>   railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in`call_app' railties
>   (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call' activesupport
>   (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in`tagged' railties
>   (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in`call' rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call' activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call' rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in`call' actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call' railties
>   (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in`call' railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call' rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call' railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call' rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in`service'
>   /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>   /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in
>   `block in start_thread'

Comment: The "image"=>#> is weird, can you check again, if this is really the output?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I think there was an escape character somewhere in the output and it was cutting out a bunch of the message. I put it in a code block and it's all there now. But the # is still there.

Comment: What if you add `include Paperclip::Glue` to the Event model?

Comment: Exact same thing happens.

Comment: Have you told Paperclip where to find ImageMagick? For me I had to add this line to development.rb: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"`

Comment: You can find where it's installed on your machine with the command: `which convert`

Comment: I did, I set it to the file path that was echoed after typing "which convert". I also went in and checked that ImageMagick is actually in that location (for me, /usr/local/bin/), and it is.

Comment: Sorry for all the guesses. I recently setup Paperclip and those were some of the issues I had. Could you post the backtrace? That might help.

Comment: One more guess while I'm at it, have you tried restarting your rails server?

Comment: Yes have restarted the server many times. I put the trace in the main post. No worries about the guesses, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong version of cocaine installed. From the Paperclip 3.4.0 gemspec: `s.add_dependency('cocaine', '~> 0.4.0')` If you look at the differences in the versions of cocaine the `run` command in the newer version takes an optional argument (`def run(interpolations = {})`) where the older version didn't. Try running `bundle update` or `bundle install` to get the correct version of cocaine. Also make sure you are running your rails server with `bundle exec rails s`, that will ensure you are using all the correct gem versions.

Comment: @mmyers89 let me know if that last comment helped and I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of cocaine. Run `bundle install` then make sure you are using `bundle exec rails s` to start your rails server.

The run method in the newer version of cocaine (~> 0.4.0) takes an optional argument (`def run(interpolations = {})`) that the older version (0.3.2) didn't.

See comments above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This fixed the error I was getting. I had purposefully rolled back to cocaine 0.3.2 because of an error from ImageMagick: "[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError". Most places, including cocaine's [Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine/issues/28) suggested rolling back to cocaine 0.3.2 fixed the problem. Obviously this is no longer the case. If I find a solution, I will post it here for anyone else with the same problem. Thanks again!

Comment: I was able to resolve the second error: I had built ImageMagick from source as is outlined on their website. It installed itself to /usr/local/bin, and I had added that path to my /config/environments/development.rb file as Paperclip describes. To fix the NotIdentifiedByImageMagicError, I completely uninstalled ImageMagick and instead of doing a make install, I did a sudo apt-get install imagemagick, which installed to /usr/bin. I updated my development.rb file to reflect that: (Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"), restarted my server, and that fixed the problem.